# Svelte TypeScript: Unexpected tokensvelte(parse-error) when adding type to an event handler

Tags: typescript, svelte

I'm trying to implement TypeScript into Svelte and has a problem like this: when I try to add type to an event in beneath line:

```
on:click={(e: Event) => onClick(e, data)}
```

it yells about:

> Error: ParseError: Unexpected token

If I remove typing it says that:

> Parameter 'e' implicitly has an 'any' type.

How can I add type to this kind of things without an error in Svelte?

EDIT:
More complex example:

```
{#each elementsArray as element}
      <CustomComponent
        on:itemClick={(e: Event) => doSomething(e, element)}>
      </CustomComponent>
    {/each}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the  [official docs](https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools/blob/master/docs/preprocessors/typescript.md#can-i-use-typescript-syntax-inside-the-templatemustache-tags), there's no official support for TypeScript in the template.

> At the moment, you cannot [use Typescript inside the template/mustache tags]. Only script/style tags are preprocessed/transpiled.

You need to move the typecasting to the `<script>` tag.

```
<script lang="ts">
  function onClick(e: MouseEvent) { ... }
</script>
<button on:click={onClick}></button>
```

In case your event is coming as a custom event from a child using `createEventDispatcher`, your `e` event will be typed as `CustomEvent<any>` and you can typecast it in the `<script>` as you please.

```
<script lang="ts">
  let elems = [1,2,3];
  
  function onClick(e: CustomEvent<{foo: string}>, el: number) {
    console.log(e.detail.name);
  }
<script>
{#each elems as el}
  <CustomComponent on:itemClick={e => onClick(e, el)}></CustomComponent>
{/each}
```

In case you still get errors for implicit any, try turning off `noImplicitAny` in your `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: But one question about that - what if I have some more properties to pass? Not only an event? Like on:click=((e) => onClick(e, someThing))

Comment: Where's that `someThing` coming from? is that a prop from the `script`? It seems to me like it's not coming from the template so I think you can just use `someThing` in the `onClick` function as a "global". It won't feel as clean, though.

Comment: Carlo, I've updated original post andd added some more complex code that explains what I'm aiming at. In that case don't know how to pass info about what element I'm clicking.

Comment: I've updated my answer to handle the more complex case. I'm not getting errors for `e` being `any`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of bugs files on this issue, e.g. [svelte/4701](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/4701#issuecomment-1500770556)