# svelte / svelte-check: Parameter 'x' implicitly has an 'any' type. (ts)

Tags: typescript, svelte

I have this code.  I am using svelte and typescript:

```
{#each $model.model.slots as slot, index}
    <th class="bg-base-300" id="field-{index + 1}">
        <div class="flex items-center"><span class="mr-1">{slot.name.value}</span>
             <span class="mt-1" on:click={(elem) => editSlot(elem,slot)}><DownCaret/></span>
        </div>
    </th>
{/each}
```

When I run `svelte-check --tsconfig ./tsconfig.json`, I get this error:

```
/Users/mikehogan/repos/personal/cozemble/monorepo/frontend/datatable/src/lib/records/DataRecordsTable.svelte:89:51
Error: Parameter 'elem' implicitly has an 'any' type. (ts)
    <div class="flex items-center"><span class="mr-1">{slot.name.value}</span>
        <span class="mt-1" on:click={(elem) => editSlot(elem,slot)}><DownCaret/></span>
    </div>
```

If I change the code to this:

```
<span class="mt-1" on:click={(elem:any) => editSlot(elem,slot)}><DownCaret/></span>
```

I get:

```
/Users/mikehogan/repos/personal/cozemble/monorepo/frontend/datatable/src/lib/records/DataRecordsTable.svelte:89:55
Error: Unexpected token (ts)
    <div class="flex items-center"><span class="mr-1">{slot.name.value}</span>
         <span class="mt-1" on:click={(elem:any) => editSlot(elem,slot)}><DownCaret/></span>
     </div>
```

What is the right way to deal with this error?

Comment: Do not add click handlers on non-interactive elements, it's inaccessible; use buttons. There is no technical error in this code, though. `elem` is not an element but a `MouseEvent`, but the language tools should be able to determine that, it is definitely not `any`. The error probably follows from an issue with the code around it.

Comment: In my experience, it is just the Svelte tools that are not perfect just yet.  If you write a function for the click event  inside the <script> tag instead of inlining it, you'll be able to specify the type using TypeScript.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. The event type could and should be inferred from the event, but svelte-check apparently cannot do that yet.

With explicit type, the correct code would be

```
on:drag={(event: DragEvent) => startDrag(event, true)}
```

but then svelte marks this as error, because [svelte doesn't support TypeScript in inline code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63337868/svelte-typescript-unexpected-tokensvelteparse-error-when-adding-type-to-an-ev) (see also [official docs](https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools/blob/master/docs/preprocessors/typescript.md#can-i-use-typescript-syntax-inside-the-templatemustache-tags) and [svelte issue](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/4701)).

Here are some workarounds:

1. Override svelte-check
2. Use helper functions:

`on:drag={startDragA}` and

```
function startDragFirst(event: DragEvent) {
  startDrag(event, true);
}

function startDrag(event: DragEvent, first: boolean) {
  ...
}
```

Obviously, the second option clutters the code and I don't recommend it. So, the best option is to just override svelte-check here.